# Krypton Suite Query

Tags: c#, krypton-toolkit, krypton

I've been using the Krypton Suite/Toolkit to great benefit, but I've always wondered why there's a free version. Is it all just a trial, and will it just cut out eventually, or is it just certain elements that are 100% free, how does that work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Component Factory website I would say that [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3) is completely free.

Purchase is required if you want to use Ribbon, Navigator, Workspace or Docking components, or need source code for Krypton Toolkit.